# Do C# Async Socket methods (BeginSend/BeginReceive, etc.) have to be static? If so, why?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

Ex. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
I am wondering if the C# methods like BeginSend, BeginReceive, etc., must be declared as static, and if so why?

I am currently building a Client/Server architecture and I want to access non-static methods/properties from inside the BeginSend/CallBack methods.

Comment: No, they do not - that is just a poor/lazy example. Just create the callbacks such that they are not static methods and *viola*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off `BeginSend/BeginReceive` are *not* static (as shown in the code example you linked to, evidenced by them being invoked through an instance of `Socket`). The reason they are *in* static methods is that the sample was meant to run from `Main` without any extra class definitions.

`Main` is a `static` method, so methods it directly invokes are also marked `static`. This then propagates to all the other methods in the sample.

In short, **No**, there is no need to run those functions from `static` methods.

For the same reason, the callback methods are `static`. If you made the initial call to `BeginSend` from within an instanced method, you could use a instanced callback/data with no problem.